# Deformacion en modo responsive de imagenes HTML

Tags: html, html5

Estoy trabajando en un pagina web, no soy bueno en diseño,
tengo un `section` con fondo de una imagen, luego unas 4 imagenes las cuales se reproducen automaticamente,
El problema es a la hora de probarlo en un movil el `section` tiene un tamaño y las imaegenes otra
Gracias

este es el link de prueba :

http://168.235.83.190/~app/img/lcn/public_html/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el codigo html :

```
<section id="text-carousel-intro-section" class="parallax" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="background-image: url(img/intro-bg/intro-bg-5.jpg);">

                    <!-- Begin cover 
                    <div class="cover"><div class="cover-inner"></div></div>-->
                    <!-- End cover -->
                    <img class="mySlides wow bounceInLeft" src="img/intro-bg/intro-bg-6.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides wow bounceInLeft" src="img/intro-bg/intro-bg-5.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides wow bounceInLeft" src="img/intro-bg/intro-bg-4.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides wow bounceInLeft" src="img/intro-bg/intro-bg-3.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="mySlides wow bounceInLeft" src="img/intro-bg/intro-bg-2.jpg" style="width:100%">

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="caption text-center text-white" data-stellar-ratio="0.5">



                        </div> <!-- /.caption -->
                    </div> <!-- /.container -->

                </section>
```

Comment: mira el de la escuela... te quedaria perfecto sin tanto codigo
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_rr creo

Comment: No revise el link que te han dejado, solo si usarás imágenes que cambiarán de tamaño sería bueno vectorizar

Comment: no eso es otro tema edite la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con ponerle estilo a las imagenes ya sea directo(en su atributo style) o dedicarles una clase

```
width: 100% ! important; height: 100%;
```

eso para cada imagen del carrusel!

De paso arregla lo del scroll agregandole estilo al body

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

... pero si es que no ocuparas scroll horizontal